# wildcard subdomains in a django project

Tags: python, django

has anyone ever used wildcard subdomains in their application? I need to come up with a way to 'localise' my application. When i say localise i mean anyone who goes to `ny.foo.com/items/new/` will be sent to a view which looks through a database and search for new items in ny. Obviously we could replace NY with any state.

Any tips would be great

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it using a middleware, eg.:

```
class StateCodeMiddleware(object):

   def process_request(self, request):
        bits = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')
        if len(bits) == 3 and len(bits[0]) == 2:
            request.state_code = bits[0]
        else:
            request.state_code = None
            # Or a redirect to the default state.
```

And then in any of your views, you can just check `request.state_code` and fetch new items only for that state.

---

**Edit:** For development, the best method is to setup a local DNS server. Eg. dnsmasq is very easy to configure:

`address=/.dev/127.0.0.1 # in dnsmasq.conf`

This makes `*.dev` point to localhost. You'll also have to configure your system to use the local DNS server (on UNIX systems you do this by placing `nameserver 127.0.0.1` into `/etc/resolve.conf`).

Alternatively, you can list all the domain names in your /etc/hosts if it is a finite set:

```
127.0.0.1 ny.localhost, az.localhost  # and so on
```

Comment: It may not always be 2 characters. Could be any amount. Also, how do I  add this to my project?

Comment: To add it to your project, you need to add it to your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES).

Comment: It says `process_request() should return either None or an HttpResponse object.`. This doesn't return anything, but rather added some variables to the request object.

Comment: It does return `None` (it's the implicit return value in Python).

Comment: Final question to expand of this subject, any idea how i would get this running using the runserver command? http://ny.127.0.0.1:8000/ doesn't want to play.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I went for the latter option, mainly because i didn't want to change the settings of my network. It works brilliantly. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: had to change def process_request(request) to def process_request(self, request) but this works great